# How do I get values from a class that depend on the one I need the value in?

Tags: c#, class, static

I have class1 and class2 that depend on each other. I need a value from class1 that screws with every thing if it is static.

This it ther relation in a nutshell

```
class one
{
    static var a;

    var b //the one that can't be static

    static var c;

    class two
    {
        public two()
        {
            do
            {
                c = f(a);
            }
            while( c == b )
    }

    public one(var A)
    {
        a = A;

        b = 0;

        for( somthing ) 
        {
            b = c;
            two();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code that shows the problem; this won't even compile.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to do this? Please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You do realize that this isn't *even remotely* valid C#, right?

Comment: Yha. But the code is a big mess so that code is better to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that you need to have a circular dependency like that, there's almost certainly a design flaw. Please see: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

If you insist, though, something like this will actually work:

```
public class A
{
    public B SomeB { get; set; }

    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int SomeVar { get; set; }

    public A SomeA { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        A a = new A();
        a.SomeB = new B();
        a.SomeB.SomeA = a;
}
```

Comment: And I can see that you did under stand that sudo code